# Reading an object's value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I want to get the features from my layer. So I'm requesting WMSGetFeatureInfo method after a successful request for GetFeatureInfo on my layer. 
The returned object is structured like this:

[image: features object]

I can read values like BEVDICHTE with `var bevdichte = features.BEVDICHTE` and so on.
But when I want to get the value of the_geom with `var the_geom = features.the_geom` it returns an object. Yes it is nested so this is intended but my question is how to get the value `ol.geom.MultiPoint`
from `the_geom`?

EDIT:

Unfortunately `var target = features.the_geom['actualEventTarget_'];` will just return another `'actualEventTarget_'` object. This is because the the_geom object is nested into infinity. I attached another screenshot to describe my problem. There are many more nested eventTargets following. Yet I was not able to get the property ol.geom.MultiPolygon.

[image: actualeventtarget(s)]

Comment: features.the_geom['actualEventTarget_'] ?

Answer (score 0):

To access a nested array, just use brackets: '[ ]'

```
var nestedArray = [[1,2], [3,4]];
var nestedArrayValue = nestedArray[0][0];
// --> returns 1
```

With your example:

```
var target = features.the_geom['actualEventTarget_']
```

By the way, from the looks of it `var the_geom = features.the_geom` doesn't seem like an array. It has keys, mapped to a value, are you sure this is an array, not an object?

Comment: You're right it is an object. My bad. features['the_geom']['actualEventTarget_'] will return another 'actualEventTarget' object. Unfortunately there are quite alot nested into each other.